# How to call a python function based on a pandas column value where the function called returns a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, oop, dynamic-programming

I have a `pandas dataframe` which list items, locations they are sold in, and the models that gave said items the lowest mape out of all models ran.

Here is a sample of what this df looks like.

```
import pandas as pd
model = ['autoarima', 'prophet', 'TES']
item = ['102354','215898','302584']
MAPE = [46.2, 23.5, 15.6]
location = ['KR_DC', 'KR_DC','KR_DC']
df_dict = {'fcast_item':item, 'location':location, 'mape':MAPE, 'best_model':model}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
```

I would like to use the value for `model` to call that model's function which is stored in a class and run the function which returns a dataframe.

For example, if the model is 'TES', then I'd like the following line of code ran:

```
df = [statmod.stats_models(df).tesa_model(target='corrected_demand', combo = combo, length=length_) for combo in combos]
```

If the model is `autoarima` then the following would be ran

```
df = [statmod.stats_models(df).arima_model(target='corrected_demand', combo = combo, length=length_) for combo in combos]
```

If it helps, the following will always be the same:
`df = [statmod.stats_models(df).` as well as `(target='corrected_demand', combo = combo, length=length_) for combo in combos]`.  Only the middle, where the model function itself is located would change.

I've never done this type of dynamic coding where a dataframe value calls a line of code to run.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use Python's built-in `exec` function, along with f-strings, whenever I have to do some dynamic coding like I use this (I'm not an expert Python programmer, so there might be a more efficient way to solve this type of problem)

Here is an example code:

```
exec(f"new_dataframe = statmod.stats_models(df).{"Your model name here"}_model(target='corrected_demand', combo = combo, length=length_) for combo in combos")
```

You might have to do some processing to your model values obtained through the original df or change the values in those df to match the function name. (Eg: df value is "autoarima" but your function name is "arima_model", so giving this value to the exec function will "autoarima_model")

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'column_name': ['function1', 'function2', 'function1', 'function2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def function1():
    print("Calling Function 1")

def function2():
    print("Calling Function 2")


function_mapping = {
    'function1': function1,
    'function2': function2,
}


df['result'] = df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: function_mapping[x]())
```

Output the result:

```
print(df)
```

Comment: My apologies.  I've just added to my question that the function being called returns an entire dataframe.  How would that work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the apply method in pandas to call a Python function based on the values in a specific column.
In this example, the custom_function is applied to the 'Age' column using the apply method. The result is stored in a new column called 'Age_Status'. The custom_function checks if the age is less than 30 and returns 'Young' if true, otherwise 'Not Young'.

You can replace custom_function with your own function and adapt the logic based on the values in the column you are interested in. This approach is flexible and allows you to use any custom function to process DataFrame columns.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I should have specified that my function returns a different dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options that return similar results. The difference is in the missing value but I believe that can also be specified.

```
v1 = [1,2,3]
v2 = ['a','b','c']
tmp_data = {'Val1': v1, 'Val2': v2}
df_tmp1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tmp_data)

df_tmp_a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ValA': [1,2]})
df_tmp_b = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ValB': [3,4]})

tmp_map = {'a': df_tmp_a, 'b': df_tmp_b}

def tmp_return_dict(row, dict_map):
    v = row['Val2']
    return_df = None
    try:
        return_df = dict_map[v]
    except KeyError:
        pass

    row['FrameRef'] = return_df
    return row

df_tmp1['FrameRef'] = df_tmp1['Val2'].map(tmp_map)
df_tmp2 = df_tmp1.apply(lambda x: tmp_return_dict(x, tmp_map), axis=1)
```

The returned dataframe is stored in 'FrameRef' column. dt_tmp1 returns NaN for c, and dt_tmp2 returns None for c. If you're just mapping via a dictionary then I believe .map() is the intended method.

You can use .apply() to a series as well but I used the row version for no particular reason.